# Using mouse axes with ePSXe?

Tags: emulation, mouse, epsxe, spyro-series

I'm using the ePSXe emulator to play Spyro the Dragon. I have a controller, but like a good PC gamer, I prefer to use keyboard and mouse. I know you can turn the camera in Spyro with the bumpers, but I'd like to turn it by moving the mouse.

Is there a way to map the X or Y mouse axis to buttons (or the joystick) in ePSXe?